# Rails includes cache not being used in model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, rails-api

So in a rails-api I'm working on, we're currently trying to optimize some of the longer running calls, and I'm having an issue with the .includes functionality. I've got it working in most situations, but there's one particular situation where it's not working in the way that I want it to.

Here's an example:

User class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  has_one :active_image, -> { where(images: { active_image: true })}, class_name: 'Image'
  has_many :facebook_auth

  def get_profile_image
    if active_image
      active_image.image.url(:profile)
    else
      facebook = facebook_auth.last
      if facebook
        "https://graph.facebook.com/#{facebook.provider_user_id}/picture?width=150&height=150"
      end
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class UserController < BaseAPIController
  def get_user_image
    user_id = params[:user_id]
    user = User.includes(:active_image, :facebook_auth).find(user_id)
    render json: user.get_profile_image
  end
end
```

With this, I would assume that the `.includes(:active_image, :facebook_auth)` would cache the data so that when I call them in the get_profile_image method, it doesn't make any more db calls, but this isn't the case. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks, 
Charlie

Comment: You have to include active_image too

Comment: Ah, that's just a typo. In my actual code I am doing that. I'll fix it.

Comment: you also have a typo in `render json: user.get_profile_image` is `render json: user.get_profile_images`

Comment: Ah, good catch, I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where almost there!
Try this approach:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :active_image,
    -> { where(active: true) },
    class_name: 'Image'

  has_many :facebook_auths, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :active_facebook_auth,
    -> { order("created_at desc") },
    class_name: 'FacebookAuth'

  scope :eager_load_image_data,
    -> { includes(:active_image).includes(:active_facebook_auth) }

  def profile_image_url
    if active_image
      active_image.url
    elsif active_facebook_auth
      "https://graph.facebook.com/#{active_facebook_auth.provider_user_id}/picture?width=150&height=150"
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller or whenever you want to eager load images:

```
# for one user, with id 2:
User.eager_load_image_data.find(2).profile_image_url

# for a collection (using 'all' here):
User.eager_load_image_data.all.map{ |user|
  [user.name, user.profile_image_url] 
}
```

This way the image data is eagerloaded, both from the *Image* class and the *FacebookAuth* class.

There where also some other issues in your method *User#get_profile_image* that I have fixed:

- It always returns nil. I am sure in your real code you have early returns.
- For collections, it does a N+1 query if looking for facebook_auth_tokens.

Comment: This looks good chipairon, I'll go ahead and try this and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure why, but this works! I think the issue was that I was doing a has_many, and then trying to do things like .last on those, and by adding those, it made it do a whole new query. Adding order desc and has_one instead of has_many is what fixed it I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wanted to comment, but couldn't put code into the comments, so I'm giving a non-answer...

I don't see anything obviously wrong, but as a work around, you could do this in User or somewhere:

```
def self.user_profile_image(user_id)
  active_image = Images.where(user_id: user_id).where(active_image: true).first

  if active_image
      active_image.image.url(:profile)
  else
    facebook = FaceBookAuth.where(user_id: user_id).last
    if facebook
      "https://graph.facebook.com/#{facebook.provider_user_id}/picture?width=150&height=150"
    end
  end

  nil
end
```

And just call/cache the image in your controller, if that's not overly simplistic...

```
def get_user_image
  render json: User.user_profile_image(params[:user_id])
end
```

That makes at most 2 relatively efficient queries. It doesn't needlessly load user, etc.

Comment: I'm just using the above code as an example. In my actual code, it's a lot more complex, and I am using the user data, and I'm actually in a loop, which is why it's important for the includes to work.

Comment: Ah. I thought that might be the case. Another workaround would be to prefetch the images in a single query and keep em in a hash table. Then, as you're looping through users or whatever, you can do a quick O(1) lookup to grab their images rather than running a bunch of queries. Basically, you'd be manually doing what prefetch is supposed to be doing.

Comment: That's actually exactly the workaround we're using. However, than we're having to use extraneous instance variables, and extra loops that I want to try and avoid. I'm sure that there has to be a way to get this to work though, so I want to see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Yeah. I want to know, too. I'm going to leave my answer up since I think your comments are helpful for others who may stumble across this. Hopefully a real answer is forthcoming...